# How can I identify if data is invalid within a data validation field using Google Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I'm creating a template in Google Sheets where users can paste their data from Excel. I have a script that ensures input accounts are valid.

The template includes data validation criteria, and I'd like my script to pick-up if any inputs are invalid according to the data validation rule. The rule requires input match data in range.

FYI - I'm new to this stuff.

I've played around with the submethods contained within SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation(), but I haven't found what I'm looking for. I tried to implement the `.setAllowInvalid(false)` method to prevent invalid inputs, however this doesn't alert the user when data is copied into the range from Excel - even if the data validation rule in the range is unchanged.

Currently I have the script check each cell with the compared data ranges, but it takes too long. Some of the data ranges in the data validation rule have over 5000 cells and the script can take over 10 minutes if the user inputs over 400 lines.

```js
function setDataValidation(sheet, fRow, fCol, numRows, numColumns, account, valid) {
  var data = sheet.getRange(fRow, fCol, numRows, numColumns);
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
    .requireValueInRange(data, true)//(range, dropdown Boolean)
    .setAllowInvalid(valid)
    .build()

   InputSht.getRange(
    FirstDataRowI,
    InputSht.createTextFinder(account).findNext().getColumn(), 
    LastRowI)
   .setDataValidation(rule)
}
```

I'd like my script to return "invalid" if the input in the range containing the data validation rule is invalid.

Something like:

```
function fillData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var lastRow = ss.getLastRow()

  for (i = 0; i < lastRow; i++) {
    aData[i] = isValid(sheet.getRange(i+1, 1))
  }

  for(i=0;i<aData.length;i++) {
    if (aData[i] == false) {
      //here I'll place my code to determine my final output
    }
  }
}

function isValid(valid) {
  var valid = true
  //code that sets valid to false if invalid
  return valid
}
```

Obviously I have no idea what I'm talking about, but hopefully someone has some insight on this.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you post your data validation rule? Also, if your final objective is to go from Excel to Sheets, you might take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56968783/problem-importing-a-large-csv-file-into-google-sheets/56970390#56970390)

Comment: The rule should be included in the first block of code. It's not so much that I want to import the data from Excel. I'm just creating a template that checks the users data for errors and alerts them. Copying and pasting from Excel seems to be the easiest thing for the users.

Comment: I found that there is an opened [request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36764218) for this. I also tried to do this by checking if the HelpText exists in the cell, but since it does no matter if the value is valid or not, it's not useful. Also, .setAllowInvalid(false) works for me to avoid users writing wrong values.

Comment: .setAllowInvalid(false) works if pasting data within Google Sheets, but when I paste data from excel into Google sheets, the cell accepts the input but shows the data as invalid. I'd like the cell to reject the value altogether.

Comment: Ok, I reported this bug into the google [Issuetracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/137256701). Meanwhile I think you can only check each cell as you have already done. I'm sorry it's so slow and tedious.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: posting this to issue tracker too.